# How do I proceed to mainActivity after setupActivity?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

After loginActivity my app proceeds to setupActivity in which user needs to input his name and there is a submit button which uploads the name to firebase and then it should proceed to mainActivity and this should happen only once for an user.**The problem is mSubmitbtn stores the name to the database but doesn't proceed to mainActivity and setupActivity pops again.**

```
public class SetupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText mNameField;
private Button mSubmitBtn;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUsers;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private ProgressDialog mProgress;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);
    mNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setupNameField);
    mSubmitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setupSubmitBtn);
    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mDatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    mSubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startSetupAccount();
        }
    });
}


private void startSetupAccount() {

    final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    final String name = mNameField.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {

        mProgress.setMessage("Finishing setup.");
        mProgress.show();


        mDatabaseUsers.child(user_id).child("name").setValue(name);


        mProgress.dismiss();

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
    }
    }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Comment: maybe, override the onpause(or onresult or onstop up to you)  functions to start the call for the main activity from there.

Comment: @koksalb Sorry I am new to android making apps from tutorials,can you help with some code examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a value in Shared Preferences that keeps track of whether the app is on its first run or not. This could go in `onCreate`, `onStart` etc.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean isFirstRun = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);

if (isFirstRun) {
    //Set value to false, so does not repeat
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isFirstRun", false);
    //show login activity
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class), REQUEST_FIRST_LAUNCH);
}
```

Comment: Not bad, but this is a login activity, so It would be necessary to have it run not just on it's first run.

Comment: I agree with Avi here. Having default shared preference is quite useful. for instance when user makes a logout you can again assign it to true to allow the login activity for the next time. You should keep track of other issues as well but it is not a bad approach for sure!